# Как получить фотографии трёхмерного объекта с разных сторон без повторяющихся областей

Tags: opencv, распознавание-образов

Объекты неправильной формы (близкой к эллипсоиду) крутятся перед камерой ограниченное время, причем с разной скоростью (непрямая зависимость от размера - чем больше, тем медленнее крутится, но еще зависит от формы, сцепления поверхности с крутящим механизмом, способности к деформации). Будем считать что один раз точно прокрутится. И вот стоит задача узнать, какой процент поверхности объекта закрашен заданным цветом (с помощью openCV). Допустим, объект прокрутился перед камерой полтора раза, и какой-то участок сфотографировался два раза, а как раз там и было цветовое пятно, которое будет подсчитано два раза. В этом и состоит проблема - как получить фотографии всей поверхности без повторов (тогда можно будет оценить количество цвета на каждой фотографии)?

Comment: @asianirish: Думаю, это вопрос к математикам.

Comment: математикам подавай сферические объекты в вакууме, а тут сугубо практическая задача, которую надо решить хоть как, без строгой теории, лишь бы работало

Comment: @asianirish, Вы хороших математиков не встречали :)



Сугобо практический подход: научитесь распознавать повтор картинки - когда пошёл второй поворот. Посчитайте, на сколько объект вращается за один кадр, какая максимальная ошибка может быть - и всё, сравнивайте попиксельно :)

Comment: Я думаю, подход примерно такой: для начала вам нужен алгоритм поиска движения, например: https://habrahabr.ru/post/201406/ (надеюсь если правильно поднастроить удастся надежно распознавать вращение), на этом же этапе можно будет оценить где фон, а где сам предмет. Далее если объект у вас близок к эллипсоиду, то можно сделать допущение что всегда элипсоид. Далее для каждого кадра смотрите насколько сместилась исходная область (если половина области новые пиксели значит вращение на 90 градусов). Если у вас мало кадров - учитавайте 1 пиксель у края элепсоида - это большая площадь чем по центру

Answer (score 1):

Есть простой вариант - с наклеить маркер (или несколько), контрастный с платформой, и по нему определять количество оборотов. Самое сложное тут - оценка площади другого цвета.
Удачи!